# What's the Wayland equivalent of ~/.xsession?

Tags: linux, fedora, wayland

As a normal, no root access, end-user of my work machine, I've always started my [windowmanager of choice](https://qtile.org) with ~/.xsession. In recent years this is done with xinit-compat, which, as I understand it on Federa, runs Xorg and then runs my user session.

The latest release of my windowmanager can function as a Wayland compositor too. How can I configure a Wayland user session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't one. You just run `qtile start -b wayland` from a virtual console, and that's it.

Whereas with X11 you needed to use xinit as a launcher to coordinate starting both Xorg and the window manager side-by-side, with Wayland you usually have a single "compositor" performing *both* tasks in the same process – in other words, the WM is its own display server.

To start applications together with the compositor, use [Qtile hooks](https://github.com/qtile/qtile/issues/685).